# How do you implement the Method makeKeyAndOrderFront:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am making a new window open and would like to implement the method makeKeyAndOrderFront: for the window, i was wondering what code i would need to enter to do this.

Here is some of the code I've already got to open the window:

File 1 (The First Controller)

```
#import "PreferenceController.h"


@implementation PreferenceController

- (id)init
{
    if (![super initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"])
        return nil;
    return self;
}
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Nib file is loaded");
}
```

File 2 (The Action Opening The Window)

```
#import "Prefernces_Delegate.h"
#import "PreferenceController.h"

@implementation Prefernces_Delegate

- (IBAction)showPreferencePanel:(id)sender
{
    // Is preferenceController nil?
    if (!preferenceController) {
        preferenceController = [[PreferenceController alloc] init];
    }
    NSLog(@"showing %@", preferenceController);
    [preferenceController showWindow:self];
}
```

The reason I am trying to do this is it has been suggested by a friend to solve a window opening problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere after `[preferenceController showWindow:self];`:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

or did you mean add a method to the controller?

```
// you should use a different method name, cause it's not the
// controller that is made key and ordered front.
- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)IBAction {
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

Comment: Do you mean after [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
} or before the } ?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to implement `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:`, you want to call it on your window in order to bring it to front and make it the key window. What does your `showWindow:` method do?

Answer (score 0):

Message `makeKeyAndOrderFront` is sent only after initiating the main event loop `[NSApp run]`. You may try to send the message from the main view by implementing the method `viewWillDraw`:

```
- (void)viewWillDraw
{
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
}
```